# Lua url pattern matching

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I have below URIs:

- `/v1/resource1`
- `/v1/resource1/{uuid}`
- `/v1/resource1/{uuid}/resource2`

I tried using `/v1/resource1` and `/v1/resource/+` as couple of patterns but the second pattern matches both 2nd and 3rd URIs

I want to have 3 separate patterns matching the above URIs separately. I am using string.match function for pattern matching.

Can someone help me with the Lua patterns?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Provide the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried using /v1/resource1 and /v1/resource/+ as couple of patterns but the second pattern matches both 2nd and 3rd URIs

Comment: Please share the code to repro the issue. Try the solution here - https://ideone.com/7sTHGs

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the solution worked correctly. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Hrishikesh P Nerurkar
I also use lua for uri-pattern (hosting a rest api). I'm using a splitting function with seperator `/` to split the several patterns in a table. It's smarter to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
string.match("/v1/resource1", "^/v1/resource%d*$")
string.match("/v1/resource1/{uuid}", "^/v1/resource1/[^/]*$")
string.match("/v1/resource1/{uuid}/resource2", "^/v1/resource1/[^/]*/[^/]*$")
```

See the [online Lua demo](https://ideone.com/7sTHGs)

**Last pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `/v1/resource1/` - a literal string
- `[^/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]*` - 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

But I think, it would be better, to have an universal pattern that works for all strings, that have the same structure. So you should avoid literal strings inside pattern (except, you are looking for exactly this).

```
list_url = {'/v1/resource1','/v1/resource1/{uuid}','/v1/resource1/{uuid}/resource2'}

patt1 = '^/[^/]+/[^/]+'
patt2 = patt1..'/%{[^}]+}'
patt3 = patt2..'/[^/]+'

for _, url in pairs(list_url) do
    print(url)
    print('\t', url:match(patt1..'$'))
    print('\t', url:match(patt2..'$'))
    print('\t', url:match(patt3..'$'))
end
```

output:

```
/v1/resource1
    /v1/resource1
    nil
    nil
/v1/resource1/{uuid}
    nil
    /v1/resource1/{uuid}
    nil
/v1/resource1/{uuid}/resource2
    nil
    nil
    /v1/resource1/{uuid}/resource2
```